# Can upgrading Ubuntu 14.0 to 16.04 affect my windows 10 installation?

Tags: system-installation

Please after the Upgrade, I can no longer choose from "which Operating system" to use. Whenever I restart my laptop, Ubuntu now becomes my default Operating system and does not give me de Options to choose the OS to use at that moment. Plz help me.

Comment: If you force the grub menu to show (hold shift or type esc repeatedly at boot time), do you still have a Windows choice, and does it work? How exactly did you upgrade? Do you still have the Windows partitions (post output of df sda )?

Comment: Wow,,,, thanks,, it's working now, after pressing de esc key repeatedly during booting. I now have the choice to choose from which windows to use at the moment.

Comment: I hold the shift  key + continues pressing of esc key ( as u guy suggested that I do) and it worked. That means I can now select which Operating system to boot from. I am really grateful for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine is booting the "wrong" operating system, you may manually select what to boot.  There are several possibilities, UEFI machines have a UEFI boot menu which may be invoked by some key (vendor specific, check the initial splash screen for info or the vendor's web site).  From the UEFI menu, you may select Windows or ubuntu.

Grub may be forced to display by holding shift key or typeing esc repeatedly at boot time -- then select what to boot from the grub menu.

Comment: I tried using the BIOS settings to manually set the booting sequence but my HP notebook UEFI menu doesn't display de operating systems. Infact whenever I set my BIOS to UEFI, and press the F10 key to save and boots, the screen will turn blue or black and says, there is Operating system and I should install on. As a result of that, I have always set my BIOS to Legacy mode.